# pytorch affine_grid: what is the theta input?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, pytorch

When trying to use `torch.nn.functional.affine_grid`, it requires a theta affine matrix of size `(N x 3 x 4)` according to the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html). I thought a general affine matrix is `(N x 4 x 4)`. What is the supposed affine matrix format in pytorch?

An example of 3D rotation affine input would be ideal. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dimensions you mention are applicable for the case of 3D inputs, that is you wish to apply 3D geometric transforms on the input tensor `x` of shape `b`x`c`x`d`x`h`x`w`.
A transformation to points in 3D (represented as 4-vector in [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) as `(x, y, z, 1)`) should be, in the general case, a 4x4 matrix as you noted.
However, since we restrict ourselves to homogeneous coordinates, i.e., the fourth coordinate must be 1, the 4th row of the matrix must be `(0, 0, 0, 1)` (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix)).
Therefore, there's no need to explicitly code this last row.

To conclude, a 3D transformation composed of a 3x3 rotation `R` and 3d translation `t` is simply the 3x4 matrix:

```
theta = [R t]
```